# Live Code runs in IIS and ASP.NET Web Server but not IIS Express

Tags: vb.net, iis-express

Having recently installed IIS Express I was hoping that it was going to make life easier for me, but I've run into a problem almost straight away.

Consider the following which is representative of some live code:

```
Public Shared Function GetServiceId() As String

  Dim principal As MyCustomAuthentication.Principal.MyPrincipal

  principal = CType(Thread.CurrentPrincipal, MyCustomAuthentication.Principal.MyPrincipal)
  .
  .
  .
  .

End Function
```

Running the code under the ASP.NET Web Server (Cassini) everything is fine and I can see that Thread.CurrentPrincipal is of type MyCustomAuthentication.Principal.MyPrincipal.

Running under IIS Express this same line throws an InvalidCastException and checking the type I find it is now of System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal which is confusing as nothing else has changed.

I can confirm that MyCustomAuthentication.Principal.MyPrincipal implements IPrincipal and remember this is Live code, it is currently deployed and working.

Can anyone shed any light on what is going on here?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Im having the same problem

Comment: @LillyPop: I'm afraid I never did resolve this -I think I ended up using full blown IIS instead and it worked fine (over a year ago now and I've moved from that job now).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want HttpContext.Current.User instead. The identity of the current User isn't the same as the identity of the current thread.

Comment: Thanks Scott - I'll give that a go when I get back to work (long weekend). I'm confused why this is working in production but not under IIS Express.

Comment: I've updated the code and the problem remains - HttpContext.Current.User comes through as a System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal and I get an InvalidCastException.